# flycheck cannot find python-pylint on macOS

Tags: python, flycheck

I have installed pylint with: `pip install pylint` and it is in the following path: `$HOME/miniconda2/bin` and I have add the following to my .bash_profile: `export PATH="$HOME/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"`

But when selection syntax checker for flycheck I get:

Syntax checker in buffer share_queries.py in python-mode:

```
  python-pylint (disabled)
    - major mode:         `python-mode' supported
    - may enable:         Automatically disabled!
    - executable:         Not found
    - configuration file: Found at "/Users/larsnielsen/.pylintrc"

Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled
checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 31snapshot (package: 20161117.144)
Emacs version:    25.1.1
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Window system:    ns
```

I am not sure why. Can someone help ?

Comment: This library is used by lots of people to set the `$PATH` on Emacs for OSX:  https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell .  Perhaps that will help you ...  I personally set the `$PATH` on either a buffer-local basis, or when firing up a particular process, which requires some advanced tinkering ....  And, there are many instances where I use the absolute path to a particular program by setting the appropriate variable(s) in Emacs; e.g., `(setq whatever-program-name-variable "/absolute/path/to/executable")`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell python-pylint exactly where to look.

This can be achieved with the following `.emacs` snippet:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
     (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "<your path to>/pylint")
     (setq flycheck-pylintrc (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/.pylintrc"))))
```

adjusting paths accordingly.

If you don`t have a pylint rc file, you can generate it with

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > $HOME/.pylintrc
```