# flycheck cannot find module for pylint

Tags: flycheck

I have installed flycheck and pylint and want to use pylint for python mode, but when selecting syntax checker with flycheck I get this:

```
  python-pylint (disabled)
    - major mode:         `python-mode' supported
    - may enable:         Automatically disabled!
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/tools/.pylintrc"
    - `pylint' module:    Missing

Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.
```

and can simply not figure out what is wrong. I have googled but cannot find the answer

Pylint is installed and can be executed from within emacs: 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of a working configuration[image: Correct configuration]

Note that executable is not that of python itself (as in your case) but to actual pylintrc that you want to use.

This can be achieved with the following `.emacs` snippet:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "<your path to>/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "/home/tools/.pylintrc")))
```

Comment: pylint is installed, using it outside emacs atm

Comment: Can you run it from inside Emacs shell? It might be installed but not seen by emacs

Comment: you can see the edit, I have made :)

Comment: If you just do M-x pylint on your python buffer, what is the output? Is the linting happening?

Comment: that I cannot do

Comment: Meaning pylint is not an option for M-x, or it silently ignores your input?

Comment: It is not an option

Comment: Apologies for being not clear. I was sugesting it only for testing purposes, not to actually use it. If it does not work, it might give more helpful debug info. If it does, it will show where to look in case of flycheck.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/flycheck-cannot-find-python-pylint-on-macos/41064#41064 this might help, worked for me.

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem on another machine but that was for the executable :)

Comment: Added update, basically /usr/bin/python -m pylint will tell the truth for this case.

Comment: should we provide full path?

Comment: @alper full path would be reliiable, yes