# How to ignore specific flycheck warning messages for Python in lsp-mode?

Tags: python, flycheck, lsp

My goal is to configure `lsp` in order to ignore warning messages for [`flycheck`](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) in Python version.

When lsp is not in use, flycheck reads from my `~/.pylintrc` file in order to ignore warning messsages. But when I enable `lsp-mode` it does not ignore the warning messages that I set in `~/.pylintrc` file.

**minimal.el**:

```
(defun flycheck-python-setup ()
  (flycheck-mode))
(require 'flycheck)
(require 'flycheck-mypy)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-flake8)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")
            (setq indent-tabs-mode  nil
                  python-indent-offset  4
                  tab-width         4)
            (let ((inhibit-message  t))
              )))
(use-package python :ensure nil)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'flycheck-python-setup)
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'python-flake8 'python-pylint 'python-mypy)
```

Having following lines in order to enable `lsp-mode`, changes the result for `helm-flycheck`.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
```

---

```
❯ cat ~/.pylintrc
disable=D100,  C0305, C0303, W291,  C0111, R0801, W0703, C0103,
```

Related: [flycheck cannot find module for pylint](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41048/18414), https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/b5lvx6/how_do_i_force_lspui_to_use_flake8/

> ```
> (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
>   (lambda ()
>     (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "<your path to>/pylint")
>     (setq flycheck-pylintrc "/home/tools/.pylintrc")))
> ```

Comment: What python lsp server do you have installed?

Comment: @Ian its `python-lsp-server==1.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `python-lsp-server`, named further `pylsp` as in `lsp-pylsp.el` file, can use `pylint` if it is enabled - you need the following code lines to be added to your lsp configuration block:

```
  ;; Adding pylint as linter for pylsp
  (require 'lsp-pylsp)
  (setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-enabled t)
  (setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-args ["--rcfile=/<absolute-path-to-home-dir/.pylintrc"]) ;; or path to your project.
```

Please note the lsp servers have their own checkers, and consequently when used, `flycheck` module should not be configured/used in any specific way - you should remove your posted configuration.

One note: your item D100 posted in your `.pylintrc` file belongs to `flake8` - you may have a `.flake8rc` file in your path.

This can be corrected also at the lsp-pylsp level, see this: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/#lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-filename - configure the variable `lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-ignore`.

Comment: I have added `(setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-ignore t)` into my init file, as I understand that will ignore `flake8rc ` file. Should I also make changes in `~/.config/flake8` file as well?

Comment: That variable is of type ```lsp-string-vector```, which means you must write ```(setq-lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-ignore ["D100"])``` - aka add to this list instead of .flake8rc file; but for other cases (aka if lsp is not in use) the error code should be also added in .flake8rc.

Comment: Everything works fine on my end, but I haven't define any `setq-lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-ignore ["D100"]) ` (should I also put it into `.emacs` file? sorry I just get lost for this line), I just put everything into `.pylintrc` under `disable=`  and I did not also create any `flake8rc ` file.

Comment: I want to apply flycheck after each save. For that should I do `flycheck-compile` and select `python-pylint`?

Comment: To answer you the question about "flake8rc": if it works for you as its is now, then it is OK. For the second one - you do not need to mix with flycheck-compile or pylint; with lsp they are all *live* enabled and used automatically; just use a buggy file and you will see the results from all tools enabled.

Comment: Ah I miss checked, warnings show up few seconds later  still I am not able to disable warnings for `D100` :( I have tried adding `(setq lsp-pylsp-plugins-flake8-ignore ["D100"])` into emacs file and also added it into `~/.pylintrc`, ~/. flake8rc `, `/project/setup.cfg` but warning message does not goes way

Comment: Try to run from terminal ```flake8``` on your buggy file - if error is still unrecognised, then check your ```flake8rc``` file or your ```flake8``` installation (dependencies: ```flake8-docstrings```?); if the error is recognised , then in emacs : C-h v ```flycheck-flake8rc``` or ```lip-diagnostic-flycheck-default-level```.

Comment: It would be helpful to try also doom-emacs, a lot of things to learn from.

Comment: Sorry for keep asking questions related to this. Emacs disables all the definitions I have in my `.pylintrc`(https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/00317b01ee84f2b073dea378999386aa) but only `D100` is not detected to be disaabled :-( `flycheck-flake8rc => Local in buffer Driver.py; global value is "~/.config/flake8"` and `lip-diagnostic-flycheck-default-level` variable does not exist

Comment: Where did you find out this "D100"? the only reference I can find out on Google is related to the Atom editor; if you know the real doc for this message please tell me. What is the text message associated to this code? (read it in emacs) - and post it.

Comment: I keep seeing: `D100: Missing docstring in public module [D100]` for not having doc under `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: To remove the D100 error, add a ```~/.pydocstyle``` file to your home dir, with the content: ```[pydocstyle]
ignore = D100
```. The same error is also generated by pylint, but with the code C0114, so you need to add this code to your ```.pylintrc``` file.

Comment: ```[pydocstyle]``` should be on single row.

Comment: I added `[pydocstyle] ignore = D100 ` into `setup.cfg` and the warning is gone! Thank you for your patient responses